# How to change autocomplete 'data' parameter without so much repetitive code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring, jquery-autocomplete

I'm trying to send different values in my `data` parameter for autocomplete, depending on a previously set global variable `lookupType`.

However, all of the other code in repeated even though only the `data` section is different.

How do I reduce the redundant code?

In one case the `data` section is this:

```
    data: {
        type: "full",
        location: "local",
        name: request.term
    },
```

while in another it is like this:

```
    data: {
        append: "no",
        doPreprocess: true,
        name: request.term,
        maxResults: 1000
    },
```

The full code is below:

```
    $( "#lookup" ).autocomplete({
    if($("#hiddenLookupType").val() == "order")
    {

        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: lookupUrl,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    type: "full",
                    location: "local",
                    name: request.term
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                // do something
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ?
                "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
        },
        open: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
        },
        close: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
        }
    }
    else if($("#hiddenLookupType").val() == "inventory")
    {

        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: lookupUrl,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    append: "no",
                    doPreprocess: true,
                    name: request.term,
                    maxResults: 1000
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                // do something
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ?
                "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
        },
        open: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
        },
        close: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
 data: {
                    type: "full",
                    location: "local",
                    name: request.term
                },
```

have:

```
data: GetData(this),


 function GetData(el)
 {
    ..Logic Here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//calling it:
var parameters =    {
        type: "full",
        location: "local",
        name: request.term
    }

test(parameters);

//the method
function test(dataList){ 
 $( "#lookup" ).autocomplete({
    if($("#hiddenLookupType").val() == "order")
    {

        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: lookupUrl,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: dataList,
                success: function( data ) {
                // do something
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ?
                "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
        },
        open: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
        },
        close: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
        }
    }
    else if($("#hiddenLookupType").val() == "inventory")
    {

        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: lookupUrl,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    append: "no",
                    doPreprocess: true,
                    name: request.term,
                    maxResults: 1000
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                // do something
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ?
                "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
        },
        open: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
        },
        close: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
        }
    }
});
}
```